# Can a single IIS server host internal and external sites?

Tags: iis

I have an on site IIS server running 2 company websites (both dot net c#).  It's binding are port 80 IP * and the URLS (DNS registered).  This works fine as the URLs distinguish them. Clearly as far as IIS is concerned, they are hitting 192.168.blah, the external addresses both being natted by the router.
I'd like to add another website for internal use only.  Can I do something like add [www.myinternalsite.com](http://www.myinternalsite.com) to the local hosts file and bind to that, so it still has a unique way to bind?
Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance and hope this question is not too vague!

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You can add multiple host name to one ip in hosts file.
website1:
[image]
Website2:
[image]
The hosts file:
[image]
They can be visited with their own host name seperately.

Comment: I assume with the IP being loopback, this is the hosts file on the server?  I assume that the hosts file on the client, would need to 192.168.0.nnn www.myinternalsite.com, for IIS to be read the postheader and get the Hostname part from it and so get the right site?

Comment: @JimTench Yes, its hosts on server. But I tried hosts on client both binding to 192.168.2.65, it also works. I don't know why actually. But sure, they have different request header with the information of URL. That could be how it works.